# Stuck tub drain

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub

I am having trouble removing a tub. Specifically, I cannot seem to loosen the drain. I've tried a proper [tub drain wrench](http://amzn.com/B004M359PC), but it still won't budge. Any ideas how I can get this thing to loosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume these are normal threads and you *are* trying to turn the wrench counter-clockwise to loosen, right?  :-)

It sounds like there may be corrosion involved, which will make it difficult to loosen. It could also be good old-fashioned pipe-dope that is thoroughly set and hardened.

A longer handle on that wrench might help (Archimedes, levers, etc.).

Also, impact can help a lot. Tapping it with a hammer while trying to turn it might do the trick. Or pounding the handle with a hammer in a counter-clockwise direction might do it.

Once you get it to *start* turning, the rest should be easier.

Of course, depending on your tolerance for replacing part of your plumbing if it breaks, enough raw physical force can solve a surprising number of problems...

Comment: You could try heating it up a bit, sometimes that will soften old plumber's putty and pipe dope. And like @Craig mentioned, try harder! I sometimes use the handles of my Channellock pliers to grab the "cross" strainer, and turn it with another large wrench.

Comment: FWIW, "raw physical force" was the solution. Took a big pipe wrench to turn the drain wrench, but it eventually loosened up. Thanks!